Very slow chunk download randomly
I got a very weird problem with my app.
I'm using a Nuxt 3 app with SSR at my production app.
As you know, when you build up your app using nuxt, it will generate a build with a lot of css and javascript's chunks, with all the compiled code.
Well, for some reason, sometimes, a random chunk takes very long to receive a response from server :( meanwhile, the app is not working...

It never throwns an error, because after waiting between 30s and 2mins, the server send the response with the chunk and all works fine, but most users will leave after waiting 3s...
Why it is randomly taking too long to download an small chunk? It does not happen in other environments.
Some tip about this issue? Could it be Nitro? I don't know how Nitro can affet it.
Is it DevOps? Is it BackEnd? Is it from infrasctruture (AWS/Cloudflare)?
Things we tested:

Removed Load Balancer: Using only one instance, no changes.
Checked CPU and RAM usages: All are in very low level.
No pattern found: It happens randomly to random chunks.
It only happens in production

I have no clue. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!
